# How to get the string between double quotes in a string in Java

Tags: java, string, quotes

For example, input will be like:

```
AddItem rt456 4  12 BOOK “File Structures” “Addison-Wesley” “Michael Folk”
```

and I want to read all by using scanner and put it in a array.

like:

```
   info[0] = rt456
   info[1] = 4
   ..
   ..
   info[4] = File Structures
   info[5] = Addison-Wesley
```

So how can I get the string between quotes?

EDIT: a part of my code->

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            String command;
        String[] line = new String[6];
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        Library library = new Library();

        command = read.next();

        if(command.matches("AddItem"))
        {
            line[0] = read.next(); // Serial Number
            line[1] = read.next(); // Shelf Number
            line[2] = read.next(); // Shelf Index
            command = read.next(); // Type of the item. "Book" - "CD" - "Magazine"

            if(command.matches("BOOK"))
            {
                line[3] = read.next(); // Name
                line[4] = read.next(); // Publisher
                line[5] = read.next(); // Author

                Book yeni = new Book(line[0],Integer.parseInt(line[1]),Integer.parseInt(line[2]),line[3],line[4],line[5]);


    }
    }
}
```

so I use read.next to read String without quotes.

SOLVED BY USING REGEX AS

```
read.next("([^\"]\\S*|\".+?\")\\s*");
```

Comment: After reading Book, change the separator to `"`. Or use a CSV parser which uses space as separator.

Comment: `new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(mystring))` should do the trick.

Comment: are the number of fields, position of the fields same every time?

Comment: Why don't you escape them? " -> \"

Comment: @MironBalcerzak Because that's not what he said he wanted to do at all.

Comment: ” or "? The double quotes are what you typed excatly?

Comment: i don't get the problem, do you want to remove " from string, or do you want to find the text by the "?

Comment: @JohnnyAW both of them. I want to remove them but also I need the value between them as a String.

Comment: @JohnnyAW He wants to do exactly what he said he wants to do when he clearly listed his desired output array.

Comment: @user3485583 Are you actually using `“` and `”`? Or are you using standard plain old `"`?

Comment: @JasonC that link saved my day thank you :)

Comment: @user3485583  As per your last edit, Did you mean to say you used like this, and your problem is solved `line[3] = read.next("([^\"]\\S*|\".+?\")\\s*");System.out.println(line[3]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative using a messy regular expression:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\w*)[\\s]+(\\w*)[\\s]+(\\w*)[\\s]+(\\w*)[\\s]+(\\w*)[\\s]+[“](.*)[”][\\s]+[“](.*)[”][\\s]+[“](.*)[”]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("AddItem rt456 4  12 BOOK “File Structures” “Addison-Wesley” “Michael Folk”");

    if (m.find()) {
        for (int i=1;i<=m.groupCount();i++) {
            System.out.println(m.group(i));
        }
    }
}
```

That prints:

```
AddItem
rt456
4
12
BOOK
File Structures
Addison-Wesley
Michael Folk
```

I assumed quotes are as you typed them in the question “” and not "", so they dont need to be escaped.

Comment: can u explain your regex. oh, its already accepted as answer. so user is gonna copy paste w/o knowing what the code is doing

Comment: i too feel regex is the way of doing this, may be because i am new to StreamTokenizer

Comment: A few alphanumeric groups \w with one or more blank spaces between them \s+ and three groups [“](.*)[”] quote, char group quote. It is not mistery. It is listed group by group. It probably could be done a lot better, simpler

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`StreamTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html) for this in a pinch. If operating on a `String`, wrap it with a `StringReader`. If operating on a file just pass your `Reader` to it.

```
// Replace “ and ” with " to make parsing easier; do this only if you truly are
// using pretty quotes (as you are in your post).
inputString = inputString.replaceAll("[“”]", "\"");

StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(inputString));
tokenizer.resetSyntax();
tokenizer.whitespaceChars(0, 32);
tokenizer.wordChars(33, 255);
tokenizer.quoteChar('\"');

while (tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
    // tokenizer.sval will contain the token
    System.out.println(tokenizer.sval);
}
```

You will have to use an appropriate configuration for non-ASCII text, the above is just an example.

If you want to pull numbers out separately, then the default `StreamTokenizer` configuration is fine, although it uses `double` and provides no `int` numeric tokens. Annoyingly, it is not possible to simply disable number parsing without resetting the syntax from scratch.

If you don't want to mess with all this, you could also consider changing the input format to something more convenient, as in [Steve Sarcinella's good suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22789557/616460), if it is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

As a reference, take a look at this: [Scanner Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

How you read from the scanner is determined by how you will present the data to your user.

If they are typing it all on one line:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String result = "";
System.out.println("Enter Data:");
result = scanner.nextLine();
```

Otherwise if you split it up into input fields you could do:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Identifier:");
info[0] = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter Num:");
info[1] = scanner.nextLine();
...
```

If you want to validate anything before assigning the data to a variable, try using `scanner.next("");` where the quotes contain a regex pattern to match

**EDIT:**

Check [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) for regex info.

As an example, say I have a string

```
String foo = "The cat in the hat";
```

regex (Regular Expressions) can be used to manipulate this string in a very quick and efficient manner.  If I take that string and do `foo = foo.replace("\\s+", "");`, this will replace any whitespace with nothing, therefore eliminating whitespace.

Breaking down the argument `\\s+`, we have `\s` which means match any character that is whitespace.

The extra `\` before `\s` is a an escape character that allows the `\s` to be read properly.

The `+` means match the previous expression 0 or more times. (Match all).

So foo, after running replace, would be "TheCatInTheHat"

Same this regex logic can apply to `scanner.next(String regex);`

Hopefully this helps a bit more, I'm not the best at explanation :)

Comment: +1 good suggestion, splitting into fields -- changing the input format is a very easy way to do this.

Comment: I use the first one. But I dont how to use regex.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this. I have prepared the demo for your requirement

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
      String str = "\"ABC DEF\"";
      System.out.println(str);
      String str1 =  str.replaceAll("\"", "");
      System.out.println(str1);
  }
```

After reading just replace the double quotes with empty string

Comment: This would not produce the output that the OP described. The OP wants to parse quoted strings as single tokens, not strip the quotes. See the example desired output.