# how to print substring between quotes in a string in Java

Tags: substring

such string:

> interface Loopback0 description "Loopback Interface for network management" ip address 10.20.30.40 255.255.255.255 no ip proxy-arp

how to print what is between " "?

> Loopback Interface for network management

Comment: Are you looking to get a substring containing what is inside the quotes?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473155/how-to-get-data-between-quotes-in-java  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574689/extract-a-substring-between-double-quotes-with-regular-expression-in-java  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789293/how-to-get-the-string-between-double-quotes-in-a-string-in-java  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484273/java-regular-expression-to-get-characters-between-double-quotes  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723523/how-to-get-string-from-several-double-quotes-in-a-line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get data between quotes in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473155/how-to-get-data-between-quotes-in-java)

Comment: Can you give a use case? Do you have one pair of ", or a variable number of "s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the " character occurs only 2 times or if you want the first pair:

```
# Get the indices of the " characters
ind1 = exampleStr.find('"')
ind2 = exampleStr.find('"', ind1+1)

# Get the substring between the two indices
result = exampleStr[ind1+1:ind2]
```

Comment: thanks, also per suggested by system similar topic worked for me:        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
       Matcher m = p.matcher(inpS);
       while (m.find()) {
             System.out.println("\nBetween quotes:"+m.group(1));
       }